# XFCE panel overlaying windows

Tags: xubuntu, panel, xfce

I have set up a panel (panel no.2, from 0,1,2 ) in xfce ubuntu, and I want it to be at desktop level - covered by windows. I found something about it on the archlinux wiki.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xfce ( ctrl+f "Panel at desktop level" )

So I did that, I created the script and run it on startup.

It took me a bit of playing until it started to work - when I set 2 as the parameter for the script. I was happy for a while, but after a restart the panel was showing over my windows again. So I played with it again, and it started to work when I set "5" as the parameter. Restart again, and same as before, panel2 is misbehaving again. 
Now, I tried to just guess-set the parameter to 8 (2+3=5, 5+3=8) , it did not work.

I would really appreciate, if I could just set it and enjoy it until I decide to change it.
What is the reason the "right" parameters change? What did I mis-understand? Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You might try enabling hiding for the panel, rather than using that startup script.  The behavior won't be quite the same as having the panel at desktop level, since the panel will be hidden even if there are no windows to cover it.  But it should be reliable.

Comment: Yes, I have it set up that way right now, but it is more of a temporary solution - you would understand better why I want it like this if you saw what I'm trying to do.